# Rise of iron: not all characters are unlocked to play the new expansion

Tags: destiny

I have pre-ordered the new expansion.

With my main character (titan), I am able to play the new expansion. Also, when I created a new hunter, I was able to play Rise of Iron.

I also have a second character that I've had since before the release of Rise of Iron (warlock), but somehow I am **not** able to play Rise of Iron with it. I am able to play The Taken King with this character. With this character, I can start the cinematic teaser/trailer for Rise of Iron, but not play it.

How can I fix this so I can start playing with my warlock? I do not want to create a new one, because I will lose everything on this character (and do not want to start over again).

I hope someone has an answer for me or a link where I can ask for help.

Comment: What level are your characters? I believe your character must be lv40 in order to start the missions, but I may be mistaken

Comment: My titan is 40, 
Warlock 25,
en new hunter 40 (with spark)

Comment: last time I got 2 sparks one for each character that already existed before the dlc (taken king, spark for level 20/25)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reach level 40 to start the Rise of Iron campaign. Your warlock can't access it because he hasn't reached 40 yet, per your comment.